# What can cause an ArcIMS server process to run away with the CPU?

Tags: arcims

We have an old application running in ArcIMS (don't ask, we're getting rid of it as soon as we can :)). All who had anything to do with the application's design or programming are long gone. We're trying to make this 9.3.1 application run in version 10 so we can upgrade our production servers to ArcGIS Server 10. Our ArcIMS runs on a server along with ArcGIS Server.

Every 24 hours or so one or more arcimsserver.exe processes go rogue and take up 99 - 100% of the CPU. On the ESRI forums this type of question doesn't seem to get a response, and ESRI support has failed to help is for the last several incidents. Does anybody here have a suggestion for what to check?

EDIT: The data includes image and map services. The data is in shapefiles and SDE.

EDIT: After some testing and exploring, we found that a database server had been moved since the application was built. The server connection was buried in the application. When we corrected it and restarted, the problem did not occur as often. After some more digging, we found other obsolete data connections. We have corrected them and now the problem occurs only about once every ten days or so.

Comment: Is this an AXL (ImageServer) service or MXD (ArcMapServer)?  Is your data in SDE?

Comment: Have you check the log files: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcims/10.0/mainhelp/topics/log_name.htm